# PostgreSQL: How to check if the value is in the list of values within the text

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a single value in one column and a string of values in another column, so how it is possible to check if a single value is in the list of values?
The goal is to find an exact value, i.e. only 'L', but not 'L' as part of 'XL'

```
with cte as
(
select 'L' as test_char, 'S, M, L, XL, XXL, 3XL' as test_column
union
select 'L', '30, 40, 50, 60, 70'
union
select 'L', '30L, 40X, 50M, 60XL, 70XXL'
)   
select test_char, 
       test_column,
       case when test_char in (test_column) then 'yes' else 'no' end as check_column
from cte
```

I try to check with `in` but can not find it. (in the third row the check_column need to be 'yes').

[image]

it is possible to convert values in strings to an array and to check each value in the array? Or any other ideas?

Comment: You want to use `LIKE`, not `IN`  - `test_column like '%L%'`

Comment: @galat based on your comment on the below answer you need to update this question.  Please update with expected output, also note that you want to check each element of the test_column as an array and not as a string.  Please note that the string is separated by ", " with a space rather than just columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to treat your string like an `array` and look at each member.  Looks like your `test_column` is separated by `", " so you could use the below

```
, string_to_array(test_column,', ') @> array['L']
```

From docs

```
Operator    Description Example                     Result
@>          contains    ARRAY[1,4,3] @> ARRAY[3,1]  t
```

[Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html)

Comment: Hi, the second row is wrong. Need to be 'no'. The goal is to find an exact value, i.e. only 'L', but not 'L' as part of 'XL'.

Comment: @galat that is not clear from your question.  Please update